# Looking for excel function to return cell above the max value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I am trying to find a formula that I will put in cell A6, that will search the cells A3:G3 for a max value and will return the value of the cell above the max value. In the case of the example photo i want the formula to be able to return the value of E2 sice E3 is the highest value.

[See photo here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZ1OC.png)

Also, in case of same values, I would like it to return all days separated with a comma or something.

I hope my description wasn't very confusing. Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no extra cell for intermediate calculation, textjoin function will be needed:

```
=textjoin(",",TRUE,if(A3:G3=max(A3:G3),A2:G2,""))
```

for the worst, just change max to min
and this is array formula, ctrl+shift+enter is required

Answer (score 1):

Why don't try the simple max to achieve the result.

```
=MAX(A3:G3)
```

Okay to get the right result, you have to do the following.

```
=INDEX(A2:G2,MATCH(MAX(A3:G3),A3:G3,0))
```

Since your data is more likely in Row, so VLookup is not useful and Hlookup won't get max. Index Match formula is used to get Max.

Comment: The problem is not finding the max value but returning the cell above the max value once found.

Comment: I have edited original reply. Check new formula to get it done.